# Plural of "roof"?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

*Roofs* is generally used, but is *rooves* archaic or just wrong?

Comment: Am only 63 but *rooves* was the plural of *roof* just like *sheep* is the plural of *sheep* etc. Am not finding the new language of the younger generation true. Where are the teachers of spelling and grammar?

Comment: Dr. Johnson's dictionary of 1755 has "In the plural Sidney has rooves : now obſolete", and *roofs* has been predominant since. If you're claiming to be over 260 years old, I think you'll find that the teachers in your day were more likely to teach to local preferences rather than anything more widely agreed as the single correct spelling; they may have been teaching *roofs* as close as the next parish.

Comment: Rooves is how I would spell it, and I'm only 32.  I'm glad to learn that my way is still in the OED.  I think most people where I come from (Lancashire, England) would at least pronounce it rooves, and while Lancashire remains in England its English should be correct.

Comment: Apparently both *roofs* and *rooves* are still in use, therefore both are correct even if one form is used more than another. However, it also appears that *rooves* falls into the same category as *warsh* ("wash"). If you say it, be prepared to be corrected or considered to be uneducated or at least provincial. I think I'll go with *roofs*.

Comment: Um, no. *Rooves* is an accepted spelling, but *warsh* is not: it is mere eye-dialect.

Comment: I was searching for clarification on this very question when I stumbled upon your discussion and felt the burning need to put my two cents in.
I was schooled in a city of 60,000 people in Tasmania, Australia. I look at, and say, the word *roofs* with a furrowed and unhappy brow. To my ear and eye the word *rooves* is correct. How can I accept, after a lifetime of usage, the term *roofs*? I will not give up on *rooves*, no matter the social consequences.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*Rooves* is not wrong per se, but extremely uncommon nowadays. Here are the stats from the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](http://www.americancorpus.org) and the [British National Corpus](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/):

```
           COCA      BNC
roofs      2307      653
rooves        1        5
```

The [Corpus of Historical American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coha/) has 6 cites for *rooves*, one from 1890, two from 1930, two from 1950, and one from 1980.

Merriam-Webster doesn't even mention *rooves* at all. The Collins English Dictionary mentions the pronunciation /ruːvz/, but not the spelling *rooves*. Finally, Wiktionary has [these usage notes](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/roof#Usage_notes):

> The plural *rooves* is uncommon and is usually considered incorrect.

So if you want to be on the safe side, I would recommend going with *roofs*, especially if your audience is American.

Comment: Of course *roofs* could also be a verb form in those corpora.  I think.  Tom and Joe can roof a house in one day.  But Tom roofs a house by himself in three days.

Comment: I must confess that I’d always thought it really ***was*** *rooves*, if a bit old-fashioned like *striven* or *trodden*. Some folks find my *roof, rooves, roofed, roofer* already exotic, since I have the **PUT** vowel there. OED gives citations for the 1300s and 1400s, plus these from the 20th century: §1903 *Dialect Notes* II. 352 ― *Roof, n. pl. rooves.* Common plural in Mass. §1938 C. Himes *Black on Black* (1973) 165 ― W’en de panic cum an’ de Lawd tek yo’ food an’ yo’ clothes an’ de rooves off’n yo’ haids, den laff.

Comment: As a 60-year-old I am entering the fray to say that at the age of 7 I was taught that both spellings were acceptable. Name of teacher and school supplied if anyone is interested.

Comment: I would be interested to see if there is a difference here between accepted spelling and accepted pronunciation. While the spelling is clearly roofs, as outlined below, those who pronounce roof with the -oo- vowel seem to often pronounce the plural as rooves. Those who use the PUT vowel in my experience use a pronunciation closer to roofs with that same vowel.

Comment: What about British English dictionaries? Can you add them to the answer? I'd imagine there'd be more of a pull towards rooves, not in the past few decades though. I still use rooves even if it gets a red squiggly underline.

Comment: In Australia, in my experience, the situations are reversed. *Rooves* is far more common, and I have been taught *roofs* as being incorrect.

Comment: @cortices - as a fellow Australian I concur on "rooves" being the most commonly used (at least by pronunciation).

Answer (score 9):

**Rooves** as a plural for of **roof** is dated, but not incorrect. The *Oxford English Dictionary* lists “rooves” as an alternate to *roofs*, one of several outdated spellings used in the UK, and in New England as late as the 19th century.

Comment: Um, as late as the 20th century, by my reading.

Comment: As late as the 21st century in the Australian vernacular in my experience! :)

Answer (score 3):

It's not stated which source Google Dictionary used but [they list](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&sa=G&rls=en&q=roof&tbs=dfn:1) both *roofs* and *rooves* as correct.

Answer (score 2):

My Concise Oxford Dictionary (1991) shows rooves as a disputed spelling

Comment: I would have thought it better classified as a disputed pronunciation.

Answer (score 2):

Johnson's dictionary notes:

> In the plural Sidney has rooves : now obſolete.

So it's been considered beyond archaic, at least by some, since the mid 18th century.

Answer (score 1):

The Dictionary of my Mac (which looks for words in the *New Oxford American Dictionary* because I set American English as default language), when I search for *rooves* it redirects me to the page explaining the meaning of *roof*, where the only reported plural word is *roofs*.